# what's standard Node class methods for singly linkedlist in java?

Tags: java, class, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I'm solving a problem on http://www.hackerrank.com related to linkedlists, in which I've to use Node class, but I didn't find Node class for linkedlists in built library as standard one, so I've to make my own. But this, problem online, doesn't let me include my own Node class into the code but I've to use it as well : as if there were standard Node class. When I use the functions defined by me as I found online, this gives a lot of errors that these functions aren't named exactly the same as I did. I don't figure out what to do. Here's my class:

```
public class Node{
    private Object element;
    private Node nextNode;
    public Node(Object data, Node node){
        element = data;
        nextNode = node;
    }
    public Object getElement(){
        return element;
    }
    public Node getNext(){
        return nextNode;
    }
    public void setNext(Node node) {
        nextNode = node;
    }
}
```

The problem is : the names I gave the functions aren't exactly the same as are accepted by the site. May be getNext is getdata or something like that. Is there any standard system to name?

Comment: Give the problem statement as it is, I guess hacker rank would have clearly specified how the `Node` class **should be/is already** structured.

Comment: No, there's no this kind of specification. I'll give you the statement.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/insert-a-node-at-the-tail-of-a-linked-list) you gave clearly says this:

```
  /*
  Insert Node at the end of a linked list 
  head pointer input could be NULL as well for empty list
  Node is defined as 
  class Node {
   int data;
   Node next;
 }
*/
```

Comment: Sir, item method is giving me an error: This symbol is nor recognized but rather "data" is used to fetch the data.

Comment: Do you mind adding the link to the hacker rank question in your description.

Comment: I've added in the comments above.

Comment: I never paid attention to the comments, but I'll do.

Comment: @lavee_singh you should :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this will work or not, but normally the setter and getter functions exactly represent the data members they are modyfying. so you may try changing the getter and setters as `getNextNode()` and `setNextNode(...)`

Comment: Error : can't find the symbol.
I've tried I few of this kind. But the parentheses aren't used, I think. But yet doesn't work.